# Relationship Mapping Restkit

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, relationship, restkit-0.20

I have two tables say Articles and Authors. Each Article have many authors and same author can be come in multiple Articles. My Json response is looks like this.

```
{
    "Articles": [
        {
            "artName": "ABC",
            "artId": "1",
            "Authors": [
                {
                    "autName": "James",
                    "autId": "200",
                    "email": "james@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                    "autName": "Mark",
                    "autId": "201",
                    "email": "mark@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                    "autName": "Robert",
                    "autId": "202",
                    "email": "robert@xyz.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "artName": "BCD",
            "artId": "2",
            "Authors": [
                {
                    "autName": "James",
                    "autId": "200",
                    "email": "james@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                    "autName": "Ben",
                    "autId": "204",
                    "email": "ben@xyz.com"
                },
                {
                    "autName": "Rayon",
                    "autId": "205",
                    "email": "rayon@xyz.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Mapping:

```
 RKObjectManager *manager = [[RestKit sharedDataManager] objectManager];
    RKEntityMapping *ArticleMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Articles" inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
    ArticleMaping.identificationAttributes = @[@"artId"];
   ArticleMaping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"artId": @"artId",
  }];


  RKEntityMapping *AuthorMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Authors" inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
    AuthorMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"autId"];

AuthorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"autId": @"autId",
@"autName" : @"autName",
@"email" : @"email"

  }];


[ArticleMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Authors" toKeyPath:@"Authors" withMapping:AuthorMapping]];
```

I have made a relationship for Articles and Authors. It is mapping correctly, but when i try to fetch the authors for "artName" ABC. i am getting only 2 authors. but when i try to fetch data for "artName" BCD. i am getting 3 authors. when checked in DB, relationship key for record "James" is overwritten by record of BCD.

How can i access all the authors for both the articles.

Note: I am using Restkit 0.20

Thank you

Comment: The relationship is many to many in the data model?

Comment: yes.. i am using many to many in DB model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the 2 objects needs to be many to many or the new assignment will explicitly break the old assignment.

When you create your `RKRelationshipMapping`, ensure that you set the `assignmentPolicy` to `RKUnionAssignmentPolicy`. The default is `RKSetAssignmentPolicy` which could be removing the existing setting.